# What is the difference between ${...} and !{...} in the Spark View Engine?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spark-view-engine

What is the difference between `${...}` and `!{...}` in the Spark View Engine?

There probably is a really distinct difference between the two, but I see them used interchangeably.

Does one encode the output and the other doesn't?  Which I have seen some discussion about in the groups?  If that is true then what does this do:

```
${H(Model.Name)}
```

Also how will setting the following in the config effect `${}` and `!{}`?

```
<pages automaticEncoding="true|false" />
```

I am hoping to document this for others as well, because the current documentation seems fragmented and out of date.

http://sparkviewengine.com/documentation/

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612411/literals-that-precede-in-spark-view-engine

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`!{...}` never encodes, `${...}` obeys the `automaticEncoding` setting and `H(...)` will always encode.