# Literals that precede { in spark view engine

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, spark-view-engine, viewengine

I was going through the [spark view engine documentation](http://sparkviewengine.com/documentation/organizingcontent) and found a lot of literals showing up in code for which I couldn’t find any references. For e.g.

`!` , `#`,  `$` , `!$` , ...

What are these for? What do the combinations mean? When do they come into use? Am I missing any more literals that precede or comes after `{`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933474/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-the-spark-view-engine

Comment: innner content:http://whereslou.com/2008/08/10/partial-files-get-a-new-powerful-trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also `?{` for [conditional output](http://sparkviewengine.com/documentation/expressions#Conditionalattributeoutput).

Answer (score 0):

Found one:

The syntax `$!{expression}` can also be used if you want to ensure any null values and NullReferenceException that result from the expression will produce no output at all.

Comment: @R0MANARMY I am just writing this as a blog entry and hopefully the most useful ones will get voted up(as opposed to everything in a single post). Points are not a concern to me. If you want the points write up relevant answers. I’ll raise a bounty and give you an extra hundred.

Comment: @R0MANARMY http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/moving-a-personal-technical-blog-to-stackoverflow-serverfault/2729#2729

Answer (score 0):

So the missing ones:

`#`: put it at the beginning of a line to insert inline c# code in the view (you must end the line with ; like any c# statement

`${}`: hope you know that one ;)

`!{}`: output without html encode the content (unsafe output)